# Copy pasting italicized content in Pages

Tags: pages, copy-paste, formatting

Pages is my word processor. I'm trying to copy a paragraph text from a docx file opened in Pages. Some words in the paragraph are italicized.

I'd like to paste it in a target doc which has paragraph styles set. When I paste I'd like to retain the italics of those words in the source doc.

The source and target docs used different styles for paragraph.

How do I paste it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the text normally, then paste using ⇧⌥⌘V. This preserves character styles such as bold and italic but uses the destination paragraph styles.

Comment: wow, what a keyboard shortcut:)